# Best way to phantom mass save all contact records

Tags: visual-workflow, workbench, updaterecord

I have created a flow to calculate a roll up summary on Account for all that Accounts Contacts.  It works well.  However, I need to save the contact record in order for the flow to work initially.  I thought i'd save all my contacts in Workbench by updating the contact object just with their IDs and nothing else.  This worked fine in the Sandbox.  Of the 20k contacts all bar 200 updated.  When I did the same in production about half failed and flow error emails started to trigger (Only a dozen or so) I did it again with just 3k records and they all failed.

So, what is the easiest and safest way to update all my contact records so that only the Flows are triggered.

I'm not a developer.

Comment: Why did they fail in production?

Comment: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER:We can't save this record because the â€œAccounts-CountContacts-AddChangeâ€ process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. <b>An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow</b><br>An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow.  Please contact your system administrator for more information. Error ID: 746528730-366900 (-1225301204)se contact your system administrator for more information. Error ID: 746528730-366900 (-1225301204):--       This is the flow that I need to run

Comment: I think from my untrained eye that I was just submitting too much data.